# PHP insert MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data from a form to MySQL db I have an html table like the one in the example below.

Table Example

Check Box | Dropdown

Check Box | Dropdown

Check Box | Dropdown

Check Box | Dropdown

All of the table and controls are being populated from db. I only want to insert the values from the drop downs where the checkbox is checked. So far it only works if the first drop down is not empty, also all of the check boxes work fine.

php code for the insert:

```
      <?php
            //$c = checkbox array which is generated from mysql db data
                $c = $_POST['check'];
//$n = dropdown array which is generated from mysql db data
                $n = $_POST['nivel'];
        //count the amount of checkboxes checked to use in for loop
                $camount = count($c);
        //count the amount of dropdowns which have a value selected should be equal to $camount but it is not
                $namount = count($n);
                    ?>



               <?php



                            for($i = 0; $i <$camount; $i++)
                            {

                                          //insert row into table for each checked checkbox
                                            $d = new Disciplina_Estudiante();
                                            $d->idestudiante = $estudiante->id;
                                            $d->iddisciplina =$c[$i];

    //this is supposed to get the values from the dropdowns that are not empty
                                            $d->idnivel = $n[$i];


                                            $d->save();               
                            }


            html markup:
            <div class="col-md-4">

                                   <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" >
                                     <thead style="background-color: #f707f3;">
                                       <tr>
                                       <th>Disclipina</th>
                                       <th>Costo</th>
                                       <th>Grupo</th>


                                       </tr>
                                   </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                   <?php foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina) : ?>

                                    <tr>


                                           <td> <input type="checkbox" id="check" value="<?php echo $disciplina->id;?>" name="check[]"><?php echo $disciplina->nombre;?></input></td>
                                            <td> <?php echo $disciplina->costo;?></td>
                                            <td><select  class="form-control" id="nivel" name="nivel[]" > 
                                            <option selected value="" readonly>Seleccionar un Nivel</option>                             
                                            <?php foreach ($niveles as $nivel) : ?>


                                            <option value="<?php echo $nivel->id; ?>"> <?php echo $nivel->nombre_nivel."<br>";?></option>




                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                                </select>
                                                </td>


                                    </tr>  
                                     <?php endforeach ;?>

                                     </tbody>

                                   </table>
                                   <br>
                                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="submit" value="Aceptar"></input>


                                   </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated first time posting...Please LMK if this does not make sense

Comment: This does not make sense. Can you trim it down to a more *minimal* amount of code that focuses exclusively on the problem at hand?

Comment: is that better?

Comment: Easy things like deleting bunches of blank lines or removing inline CSS that isn't relevant goes along way towards showing you're staying focused on the problem at hand. The most important thing to do when debugging is to remove everything that's not causing the problem until you narrow it down to the thing that is. (Also, yikes, inline CSS? Please, stylesheet that!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that whilst only the checkboxes that are checked are passed in the `$_POST` array, ***all*** of the `select` boxes are passed whether the user selected a value or not.

What you can do in this case is index your checkboxes in the `name` attribute so that index `i` of the `$check[]` array will match index `i` of the `$nivel[]` array. Like so:

`<input type="checkbox" id="check" value="<?php echo $disciplina->id; ?>" name="check[0]" />` (**By the way**, `input`s are self-closing elements.)

Which would correspond to the select: `<select  class="form-control" id="nivel" name="nivel[0]" >`

Then change your loop for a foreach like so:

```
foreach ($c as $i => $checkbox) {
    $d = new Disciplina_Estudiante();
    $d->idestudiante = $estudiante->id;
    $d->iddisciplina = $checkbox; 

    $d->idnivel = $n[$i];
    $d->save();
}
```

As a final note, **please** indent your code.

Comment: **Thank you very much** that solved my problem. BTW i just like to close my inputs in that manner. Personal preference I guess.

Comment: You're welcome :) FYI, the [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) clearly states that you should not add a closing tag to void elements like `input`... it's not so much a question of personal preference as it is of correctness.

Comment: @IFigs That's XHTML which is superficially simlar to but not equivalent to HTML5. If you're learning, [use a validator](https://validator.w3.org) to verify you're writing your code correctly. Personal preference is an obstacle if browsers will interpret your HTML incorrectly.